# Place legend at specific heatmap.2 column and row in r

Tags: r, legend

Is it possible to place a legend at a specific column & row in heatmap.2?

I.e.

```
> mymatrix = matrix(0,2,2)
> mymatrix
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0

heatmap.2(mymatrix, col=bluered, Rowv = FALSE, trace="none", Colv = FALSE, main="Legend positioning")
```

I'd like to mark a circle, via legend, at mymatrix[2,2] in the heatmap.2

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I have decided to make another matrix which marks the specific coordinate and note this matrix in heatmap.2

> mymatrix = matrix(0,2,2)
>   note.matrix = matrix(,2,2)
>   note.matrix[2,2] = "|"
>   mymatrix
>        [,1] [,2]
>   [1,]    0    0
>   [2,]    0    0
>
> note.matrix
>        [,1] [,2]
>   [1,] NA   NA
>   [2,] NA   "|"
>
> heatmap.2(mymatrix,cellnote=note.matrix,notecol="black")

Images an heatmap, where column 2 + row 2 is marked with |.
If there is a more convenient way, let me know